# How to enable diagnostics logs for storage accounts using azure resource manager templates?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-storage-account

I am trying to create an azure resource manager template to provision storage accounts, and I want to enable diagnostics logging on creation.

Basically I am trying create a resource manager template to achieve the same result of them Cmdlet [Set-AzureStorageServiceLoggingProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/set-azurestorageserviceloggingproperty?view=azurermps-6.13.0) so that the diagnostics logging is enabled on creation time, instead of enabling this manually every time a storage account is provisioned.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this [github](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/13195) thread in azure docs, it says that this feature is not supported yet, and it will be supported in the second half of calendar year 2019.

And the recommend way for automating this task is using powershell & c# commands.